# How to get my activity page to load up Imagebuttons depending on the values of another activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, arraylist

So I basically have 3 activity pages right now
1st: only a start button
2nd: a bunch of question using RadioGroup, spinners, and text values
3rd: I want this page to present Imagebuttons I already have but depending on what value the user entered in activity 2

I'm making an android app using Java, eclipse.

Comment: your question was to get value from one activity to another or loading imagebuttons??

Answer (score 1):

You could pass datas between your activites using the extras.

From the SecondActivity :

```
Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
i.putExtra("variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

From the ThirdActivity :

```
String value;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    value = extras.getString("variable_name");
}
```

Then just load the appropriates resources from what datas you get from the `Bundle`

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setBackgroundDrawable`() on a `Button` to set the background of the button.

Any text will appear above the background.

If you are looking for something similar in `xml` there is: `android:background` attribute which works the same way